# UIBarButtonItem. How to show the toggled status if button will be pressed?

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

I am searching for a solution how could I show that the UIBarButtonItem is pressed. So I can show the user if some button is pressed?

So I want to show if the user pressed locate me button or not.

Some ideas how I could do that?

Comment: what do really mean. Do you want to keep the button in the pressed state or do you want to show somewhere else that that button is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I did it!

```
- (IBAction) displayPoiMarkers {

    if (displayPoiStatus) { // remove the markers

        // Button style change.. looks not pressed
        displayPoiButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;

    } else { // display the markers

        // Button style change.. looks pressed
        displayPoiButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
    }

}
```